# three.js with physijs cannot JSONLoad animated model, worked on three alone

Tags: model, three.js, physijs

Working with three.js r68/r70 I succeded on importing these two models before I inserted physijs, but I get errors on JSON now that I have physijs scene(). I'll upload whole project and hopefully someone can find a way for this to work.

Here is the link to .rar file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5Q46w85ZaddEE3MFJrWDhIRlk/view?usp=sharing

And as suggested jsfiddle, tho I'm not sure is this properly done.

https://jsfiddle.net/jjagy5w4/

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(true);
var logging=loader.load('/js/md2droid.js', function (geometry) {
   // player.mesh = new THREE.MorphAnimMesh(geometry, materials);
    player.mesh = new Physijs.ConvexMesh(geometry, material);
```

Thanks in advance,
Darko

Comment: You will probably get more help if you add a jsfiddle link rather than a .rar file.

Comment: Edited Question, but since I'm only beginner in js, this is first time I used jsfiddle, so hope to get an insight into what went wrong in my code.